# On AIX, doing a tail -f stop logback to log message on a file

Tags: java, unix, logback, tail

I am using logback in a web application deployed on weblogic
Logback is working well and produce an output file but each time i try to do a tail -f on this file, no more entry are written in the file...
I have try to set the prudent mode but this has not solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue... i forgot to put the append property...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.